# Python alternative for MATLAB code 'min(Ar_1(Ar_1~=0))'

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

**I want to achieve the same result with least complexity in python as `min(Ar(Ar~=0))` in MATLAB** where `Ar` is a 2D numpy array.

For those who are not familiar with MATLAB, `~=` means `!=` or *not equal to*.

**Is there a function in python which returns the indexes of the elements:**

**1.** Whose values fulfill a condition *(elements which are != 0 in this case)* 

**2.**
Which can directly be used as list index input for another array? *(As `(Ar~=0)`'s  result is being used as an input like this `Ar(Ar~=0)`*

Here `Ar~=0` has been used as list index input like this `Ar(Ar~=0)` and then min of the array `Ar(Ar~=0)` is being found out. In other words minimum value of the array is found out excluding the elements whose value is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python syntax for a numpy array A would be:

```
A[A!=0].min()
```

you can also set the array elements:

```
B = A.copy()
B[A==0] = A[A!=0].min()
```

just as an example setting a cutoff

Comment: Yes, this worked. Can't believe it was so simple! Thanks mate :D Although,  `B[A==0] = A[!=0].min()` doesn't seem to work. I understood the logic behind it though. Could you explain what this line is doing exactly?

Comment: Its important that the size of arrays on both sides is the same or (as in the expample) that the right side is a scalar